# How to modify v-for or use v-for with different step?

Tags: vue.js

Let's say that I have an array

> arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

How can I use v-for to get the following result:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="elem in arr">
            // here i need to produce a div every 4 steps
            // each div will contain 4 elements in right order
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name:home,
    data(){
        return {
            arr:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

So I get 3 div and each one contains 4 elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your component definition:

```
data: () => ({
    arr: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
}),
computed: {
    chunkedArr() {
        const result = []
        for (let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i += 4)
            result.push(this.arr.slice(i, i + 4))
        return result
    }
}
```

In the template:

```
<div v-for="a in chunkedArr">
    <div v-for="i in a">{{ i }}</div>
</div>
```